# SqlCommand string not working in Management Studio

Tags: t-sql, select, syntax, vb.net-2010

I have this line in my VB.net app:

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select TOP 1 Record from [SRFeedData_Local].[dbo].[Record] where Record LIKE '%" & CRIS & "%'", con)
```

This works fine, but if I try and run this query from within SQL Server Management Studio like this:

```
select Record 
from [SRFeedData_Local].[dbo].[Record] 
where Record like '%" & 'SGWSM94VMW0000146' & "%'"
```

it complains about the syntax.

Why the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `+` instead of `&`

Something like

```
select Record 
from [SRFeedData_Local].[dbo].[Record] 
where Record like '%' + 'SGWSM94VMW0000146' + '%'
```